# Trying to use deadline_timer to add timeout to read_until

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Maybe I am misunderstanding how things work, but I am trying to add a timeout to a `read_until` call, so I created a `deadline_timer` and started it before calling `read_until`, but the `read_until` still blocks everything, and the timer never gets activated.  Am I doing it wrong?  Below are some snippets from my code.

```
void MyClass::handle_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    // Our deadline timer went off.
    std::cout << "Deadline Timer was triggered." << std::endl;
    Disconnect();
}

// Read some data.
void MyClass::ReadData(){
            boost::asio::streambuf response;
            deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT));
            deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&MyClass::handle_timeout, this, _1));

            boost::asio::read_until(socket_,response,asString);
}
```

Comment: Do both, the timer and the socket use the same io_service? If not, that's the reason.

Comment: Yes they are both constructed with the same io_service as their argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're misunderstanding how things work. If you [desire cancelability,](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2832) you need to use the asynchronous methods such as

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(...);
```

instead of

```
boost::asio::read_until(socket_,response,asString);
```